# Faulty graphics card or maverick's issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, graphics

I've started to get strange artifacts on my 2010 MacBook Pro after updating to Maverick's. I'm not sure if they occur systematically -- I am running a CPU intensive script this time, but have run the same script before without issue. Restarting seems to fix it.

From other posts, it sounds like it most likely is a graphics card issue, but I was wondering if it is potentially an issue relating to the Maverick's update, rather than a graphics card problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am having precisely the same issues with the same MacBook Pro, a 2010 15" 2.4GHz i5. When I uncheck the 'Automatic graphic switching' box in Energy Saving in System Preferences, the artefacts immediately disappear. My guess? A Mavericks driver issue with Intel HD graphics in this laptop.

Comment: I have exactly the same kind of problem with my MBKPRO 15 2.4ghz i5. As u've done, I Went in system preferences and uncheck the automatic graphic switch button. Result, it immediately disappeared too! Thx u!